# session not storing the data between 2 pages by calling session_set_save_handler

Tags: php, session

I searched this question through out on here..but i cant to get right answer...So please go through my question & answer me please...thanks is advance..

`-------------- Session.php ------------------------`

```
<?php
class WSession
{
    function __construct() {
    }

    function sess_open($sess_path, $sess_name) {
        return true;
    }

    function sess_close() {
        return true;
    }

    function sess_read($sess_id) {
        mysql_connect("test", "test", "test");
    mysql_select_db("test");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT Data FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            //Session found, pull out data field value
            $sess_Data = $results->data;

            $CurrentTime = time();
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessions (SessionID, DateTouched) VALUES ('$sess_id', $CurrentTime);");
            return $sess_Data;
        } else {
            $CurrentTime = time();
            extract(mysql_fetch_array($result), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'sess');
            mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET DateTouched = $CurrentTime WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
            return "";
        }
    }

    function sess_write($sess_id, $data) {
        mysql_connect("test", "test", "test");
    mysql_select_db("test");        
        $CurrentTime = time();
        mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET Data = '$data', DateTouched = $CurrentTime WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        return true;
    }

    function sess_destroy($sess_id) {
        mysql_connect("test", "test", "test");
    mysql_select_db("test");        
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        return true;
    }

    function sess_gc($sess_maxlifetime) {
        mysql_connect("test", "test", "test");
    mysql_select_db("test");        
        $CurrentTime = time();
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE DateTouched + $sess_maxlifetime < $CurrentTime;");
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

`------------------- Index.php ---------(MAIN FILE)----------------`

```
require_once(session.php);

$handler = new WSession();
session_set_save_handler(array($handler, "sess_open"),
                         array($handler, "sess_close"),
                         array($handler, "sess_read"),
                         array($handler, "sess_write"),
                         array($handler, "sess_destroy"),
                         array($handler, "sess_gc"));

register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

session_start();

$_SESSION['test']   = "testado";
```

and followed by this, we are calling login controller(Ex: login.php).

`---------------------- login.php ----------------------`

after redirection, here we are trying to save sessions using save handler.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "XXXXXX";

$_SESSION['testing'] = "XXXXXX";
```

But its not writing above values to DB.

---

Its storing only the first data which is in the main file,

`test|s:9:"testado";`

Can you please guide to save other values too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve a similar thing. But I'm using PDO and I call session_set_save_handler in constructor in class Session.

Take a look at this simple tutorial http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Storing-PHP-Sessions-in-a-Database/

Make sure that your session is running on login.php before you set something to $_SESSION.